# Chat com nodejs e mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js

Criei um *chat* com nodejs e MySQL pra buscar informação do *user*... mas estou com um seguinte problema: quando cai a conexão ou reiniciar o servidor nodejs, não volta logando usuário e senha. Alguém tem uma dica de como fazer isso que ao cair ele volta logando?

OBS: eu consegui fazer ele acessar o MySQL e entrar na sala... só que quando volta o *nick* fica como `NULL` ele não ta conseguindo achar esses dados quando volta. Alguém tem uma sugestão?

Comment: esta usando o socket.io ?

Comment: @SneepSNinjA, sim estou

Comment: Sim pessoal mais não e o reconect do servidor e sim do usuario de senha do chat... eles se perdem ja tentei localstorage localsession

Comment: Vou votar na sua pergunta porque já vi que mais pessoas estão começando com node e isso vai ajudar todos que estiverem iniciando :)

Comment: @SneepSNinjA , vlw depois vou organizar e deixar tudo bem claro pro pessoal :D

Comment: Depois coloca você mesmo uma resposta de como resolveu e aceita ela para fechar o assunto certinho

Answer (score 0):

passa parametro de reconect assim:

```
io.connect(                                                             // CRIVAR UM SOCKET
            $("#socket").val(),{                                            // ENDERECO DO SOCKET
            'reconnect': true                                               // que irá informar se o socket irá tentar se conectar caso perca a conexão com o Server.
           ,'reconnection delay': 500                                       // informa o tempo em milissegundos que será o delay da tentativa de conexão.
           ,'max reconnection attempts': 1000                               // informa o valor máximo de tentativas de conexão com o Server.
           ,'secure': false                                                 // informando se a conexão com o Server irá utilizar criptografia (conexões HTTPS).
    });
```

Comment: Sim pessoal mais não e o reconect do servidor e sim do usuario de senha do chat... eles se perdem ja tentei localstorage localsession

Comment: o usuario e senha do chat você esta armazenando onde?

Comment: então não achei um local no html para guardar, que ele consiga recurar

Comment: @Willian já pensou em cookies de sessão?

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento, entao pelo navegador?

Comment: @Willian cookies de sessão são algo do HTTP e não necessariamente precisa de um navegador, como você mencionou html, imaginei que ou fosse uma página web ou um webapp, em ambos é possivel implementar "cookies de sessão" que são diferentes de "cookies normais".

Comment: Estou por fora de node.js, mas acredito que você poderia usar o `var express = require('express'); ... express.cookieParser` @Willian - o SneepSNinja parece ter dominio, acredito que logo ele irá lhe indicar algo neste sentido

Comment: @Willian a conexão com o MySql é feito com o node-mysql ou você faz um ajax em php, tem um link aqui que o cara usa um pool para manter em cache as conexões ve se resolve https://codeforgeek.com/2015/01/nodejs-mysql-tutorial/

Comment: @SneepSNinjA tipo essa conexão eu faço o problema e se a internet cair ou o nodejs cair... ele não volta com o usuário e senha... queria que volta-se usuário identificado como se nada tivesse acontecido... o chat ja volta-se com o usuário identificado

Comment: @Willian então acho que você vai ter que usar session, eu implementei meu node com ajax e php, mas node puro como você esta usando não cheguei a usar... tem um outro link aqui que ensina a usar session no node https://codeforgeek.com/2014/09/manage-session-using-node-js-express-4/

Comment: sim era isso que procurava esse negocio de session vlwww :D

Comment: @SneepSNinjA e sobre isso vc sabe: na verdade to usando puro pq axo que e a unica forma... o que queria mesmo era desenvolver tudo em php e angular e usar o node apenas na parte de enviar msg e identificar o user para o chat que usa a db mysql... pois o foda que quando roda o node app.js ele acaba gerando um site tem como eu nao usar esse site? fazer tudo em servidor apache? usuario node apenas para o chat e notificações seria top demais

Comment: eu abri um chat caso queria mais alguma coisa, mas vou procurar incentivar a criar novas perguntas para que toda a comunidade receba também.. segue http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/25423/nodejs